# TypedDict, illegal target for annotation when using attribute of another TypedDict in definition

Tags: python

I have 2 TypedDicts and in the latter I want to use an attribute of the former in the definition.

```
class Detail(TypedDict):
    id: Optional[str]
    to_date: Optional[str]
    from_date: Optional[str]
    
class Overview(TypedDict):
    id: Optional[str]
    'Detail.to_date': Optional[str]
```

The code is only running because of an import statement so there is no use of it to detail for the question.

Error:

```
'Detail.to_date': Optional[str]
    ^
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly specify type for `to_date` in class `Overview`.

```
class Detail(TypedDict):
    id: Optional[str]
    to_date: Optional[str]
    from_date: Optional[str]
    
class Overview(TypedDict):
    id: Optional[str]
    to_date: Optional[str]  # Directly define the type
```

Comment: Yes, but `to_date` should explicitly be a `Detail` `to_date` and should follow the same type if it's changed in `Detail`. My goal is to ref the attribute of that class in the definition of the other.

Comment: AFAIK, Py's type system does not directly support referencing or inheriting types of individual fields between TypedDicts in this way.